# How to send a file as an input to another file?

Tags: command-line, scripts, redirect

Through the command shell we can redirect the three standard filestreams so that we can get input from either a file or another command instead of from our keyboard, and we can write output and errors to files or send them as input for subsequent commands.

So why can't we give input to an other file as

```
~# /root/Documents/text1.txt > /root/Documents/text2.txt
```

Answer (score 17):

You can't use `file1 > file2` to copy `file1`'s contents to `file2` because there's no command there. You have to issue some command.

- Redirections apply to (1) a command you run or (2) the shell as a whole (if applied to the `exec` builtin). But they work by changing the source or target of actions that perform input-ouptut operations--that is, that read from or write to a file or device. You have to actually perform some action.
- `file1 > file2` is a valid command, under some circumstances, but it doesn't copy `file1` to `file2`. Instead, as [l0b0 says](https://askubuntu.com/a/524594/22949), it attempts to *run* `file1` as a program or script, and--whether or not that succeeds--sends the [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) from running `file1` into `file2`. (If `file2` is a regular file, it gets overwritten.)
- It's tempting to think something like `<file1 >file2` would work. But it does not: when you leave off the command, no operation is performed. `file1` is used as input and `file2` is used as output... but since *nothing is actually done*, the output is empty, the only effect is to (a) create `file2` if it didn't already exist, or (b) make `file2` empty if it did:

  ```bash
  ek@Ilex:~$ echo foobar > file1
  ek@Ilex:~$ echo quux > file2
  ek@Ilex:~$ cat file1
  foobar
  ek@Ilex:~$ cat file2
  quux
  ek@Ilex:~$ <file1 >file2
  ek@Ilex:~$ cat file2
  ek@Ilex:~$ file file1 file2
  file1: ASCII text
  file2: empty
  ```

### You probably just want to run `cp file1 file2`.

Assuming, that is, that `file2` is a regular file (or doesn't exist but you want it to exist as a regular file after your command runs), you should probably simply use the [`cp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/cp.1.html) command.

As [Sylvain Pineau says](https://askubuntu.com/a/524591/22949), you can use `cat file1 > file2` as well. However, the `cp` command is well-behaved when writing to a file that already exists: it overwrites the target with the source, but keeps the target's original [permissions mask](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) (and therefore is good even in situations where one might intuitively think `cat file1 > file2` were needed):

```bash
ek@Ilex:~$ echo glockenspiel > file1
ek@Ilex:~$ echo flugelhorn > file2
ek@Ilex:~$ cat file1
glockenspiel
ek@Ilex:~$ cat file2
flugelhorn
ek@Ilex:~$ chmod +x file2
ek@Ilex:~$ ls -l file1 file2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ek ek 13 Sep 16 03:28 file1
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ek ek 11 Sep 16 03:28 file2
ek@Ilex:~$ cp file1 file2
ek@Ilex:~$ cat file2
glockenspiel
ek@Ilex:~$ ls -l file1 file2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ek ek 13 Sep 16 03:28 file1
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ek ek 13 Sep 16 03:28 file2
```

### To *append*, you probably do want a (different kind of) redirection.

Both the `cp` command and redirection with `>` will *overwrite* the contents of a regular file, if it exists. But `>>` redirection appends.

So if you want to append the contents of `file1` to `file2` instead of overwriting `file2` with the contents of `file1`, a redirection with `>>` (*not* `>`) is a good choice:

```bash
ek@Ilex:~$ echo 'Violets are blue.' > file1
ek@Ilex:~$ echo 'Roses are red.' > file2
ek@Ilex:~$ cat file1
Violets are blue.
ek@Ilex:~$ cat file2
Roses are red.
ek@Ilex:~$ cat file1 >> file2
ek@Ilex:~$ cat file2
Roses are red.
Violets are blue.
```

Answer (score 8):

You can redirect the content of text1.txt using the `cat` command:

```
~# cat /root/Documents/text1.txt > /root/Documents/text2.txt
```

**Note**: you can use `cat` to also create new binary files, e.g:

```
~# cat mypic.jpg > my_new_pic.jpg
```

Comment: The other answer seems to try its best to make the whole thing seem way too complicated.

Yes, in this simplistic example you can just use `cp`.  However, I interpret the OP's question as being about how to pipe from a file in general.

And in that sense, this is the best answer.

In short, `cat` is an essential, common command for lots of command line tasks.

Comment: @neon_overload The question here is about redirection, not piping. (I'm not disagreeing with the part of your comment that says this answer is valuable--*this answer* does not confuse those two concepts.) A question about how to *pipe* from a file *in general* would need answers that talk about pipes (with `|`). A question about how to *redirect* from a file *in general* would need answers explaining how to redirect *from files*, with `<`, as [nux's](http://askubuntu.com/a/524673) and [Stephen Quan's](http://askubuntu.com/a/525017) answers do but which neither this answer nor mine does.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [@SylvainPineau's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/524591/10371), the reason you can't do `/root/Documents/text1.txt > /root/Documents/text2.txt` is that the thing separate from the redirect operator and the file after it has to be a *command.* When you execute `/root/Documents/text1.txt > /root/Documents/text2.txt` you are telling the shell to *execute* `/root/Documents/text1.txt`, which probably won't even run since text files shouldn't have the execute flag set, and save standard output to `/root/Documents/text2.txt`. Since standard output from that "command" is empty the target file will be empty.

Comment: To be pedantic, the redirection can appear anywhere. For example `> out date` successfully writes the current time to the file "out".

Answer (score 0):

Command output Redirection :

```
ls > file.txt
```

ls gives a directory listing and the output of ls command is redirected to file.txt .

Error Redirection :

```
command 2>~/Desktop/errorsfile.txt
```

This will redirect the error result of command to a `txt` file.

For file content redirection :

1. `cat file1 > file2` (will copy the content of file1 to a new file file2)
2. `cat file2 >> file1` (here will copy content of file2 to an existing file file1 without deleting its content )
3. `cat file1 file2 > file3` (This would add the contents of ' file1 ' and ' file2 ' and then write these contents into a new file named ' file3 ' )

I would also like to add The Input Redirection :

```
$ mail -s "Hello World" user@yourmaildomain.com < /home/user/mailcontent.txt
```

Here if the mail body is in a file then we can use it directly to send the mail.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already stated, you're missing a command. Here are some interesting combinations:

```
cat <file1.txt >file2.txt
tail <file1.txt >file2.txt
head <file1.txt >file2.txt
wc -l <file1.txt >file2.txt
base64 <file1.txt >file2.txt
base64 -D <file1.txt >file2.txt
gzip -c <file1.txt >file2.txt
gunzip -c <file1.txt >file2.txt
```

The spirit of piping/redirecting indicates that a command (such as copying, extracting, counting, encoding/decoding, compressing/decompressing) is needed to specify the action to transform the input `file1.txt` into output `file2.txt`.